# UIViewController with two UITableView and Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, autolayout

I have a `UIViewController` with two `UITableView` like this

[image]

when the interface rotate I would like this interface

[image]

but with Autolayout I can't be able to achieve this.

Here the constraints for table view A:

- Leading space
- Bottom space
- Top space
- Align center Y

and for table view B

- Trailing space
- Bottom space
- Top space
- Align center Y

and here the result:

[image]

If I add the constraint horizontal space between table view to 0 here is the result

[image]

How can I solve it without setting programmatically the frame? I wanna using Autolayout.

### Solution based on @sha answer

Constraints for table view A:

- Leading space
- Bottom space
- Top space
- Width equals to B
- Horizontal space from B = 0

and for table view B

- Trailing space
- Bottom space
- Top space
- Width equals to A
- Horizontal space from A = 0

Comment: @ParvendraSingh : frame don't work in autolayout...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove align Y constraint (you don't need it if they take all available height) and add one to make width the same for A and B.

Comment: No, I'll get the behavior described in 3rd image. A on the left, space, B on the right.

Comment: If you add constraint to have same width you will get exactly what you need. You still keep one with 0 between them.